# Removing data from a dataframe CSV (Issues with .drop function)

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, loops, python-dataclasses

```
#2000: 200,000
#2001: 200,000
#2002: 300,000
#2003: $300,000
#2004: $300,000
#2005: $316,000
#2006: $327,000
#2007: $380,000
#2008: $390,000
#2009: $400,000
#2010: $400,000
#2011: $414,000
#2012: $480,000
#2013: $490,000
#2014: $500,000
#2015: $507,500
#2016: $507,500

import operator
import functools
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class SalaryItem:
    salary: int
    years: list

items = (
    SalaryItem(200000, ['2000', '2001','2002']),
    SalaryItem(300000, ['2003', '2004']),
    SalaryItem(316000, ['2005']),
    SalaryItem(327000, ['2006']),
    SalaryItem(380000, ['2007']),
    SalaryItem(390000, ['2008']),
    SalaryItem(400000, ['2009', '2010']),
    SalaryItem(414000, ['2011']),
    SalaryItem(480000, ['2012']),
    SalaryItem(490000, ['2013']),
    SalaryItem(500000, ['2014']),
    SalaryItem(507500, ['2015' , '2016']),
)

for item in items:
    Remove = SalariesCSV[
        (SalDf['salary'] == item.salary) &
        functools.reduce(operator.or_, (SalariesCSV['yearID'] == year for year in item.years))
    ].index
    SalariesCSV.drop(Remove, inplace=True)
    
SalariesCSV = SalariesCSV.drop(Remove)

print(SalariesCSV)
```

This is the code I've written to remove observations with Y Salary in X year.

I am a novice in Python. I'm trying to do my first EDA project in it using baseball data. But everytime I print the new dataframe its still the same as the prior (before this code). This is the third way I've tried to remove the data in terms of type of code, I am just lost and google is not helping. Appreciate any feedback, please be aware I am a NOVICE. But I
am very much ready to learn

I tried to remove The given salaries for given years from the dataframe so I could exlpore the trends between MLB player salaries and injuries, position, and other statistics. I did not want to include the players getting paid league minimum because they are usually under contract to where they do not have control over their salaries, making them unable to leverage their statistics until arbitration. My goal is to create some type of Machine Learning Model.

I had actually ommitted 20 years of data already before this line of code, but after trying multiple ways through blocky and messy code, I tried using a loop upon someone elses suggestion and I'm still not able to remove these observations from the data frame. The dimensions end up being the same as they were before.

Comment: Can you give us more info about `SalariesCSV` and `SalDf` ? A minimal example of what these objects are would be welcome

Comment: I have since figured it out, actually. Thanks for the reply!